# 'The punch of keys' or 'the punches of keys'?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

No need to delay
The punch of keys
That crunch of ease
As if the screen didn't freeze

This is a poem I'm writing. I need punch to go with crunch. The problem is, it probably has to be 'the punches of keys' (meaning, the keys when you type on a keyboard)

Can the punch of keys be considered grammatically correct? As in, the concept of punching in keys can be known as 'the punch' of keys.

Comment: It's poetry — so anything goes. However, you could use gerunds and be technically accurate: *...the punching of keys That crunching of ease...*

Comment: @TinfoilHat thank you!! I will do that <3